# Can not access user control component

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

In my user control I have a datagridview named `dgvCustomers`, I want to load customers in the gridview like:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    db = new DatabaseContext();
    dgvCustomers.DataSource = db.Customers.ToList();
}
```

But I can not access the datagridview, how can I do this?

This is the erro which I receive:

> The name dgvCustomers does not exists in the current context.

The name of the user control is CCCustomers.

Comment: What is error you get it?

Comment: The name dgvCustomers does not exists in the current context the name of the user control is CCCustomers

Comment: Well, it is impossible to tell from the small fragment of code you've shared. Is the `dgvCustomers` a really member variable of the same `Form` object which `Form1_Load` method you have copied?

Comment: Share whole `Form.cs` and `From.Designer.cs` files

Comment: The easiest solution would be changing `Modifiers` property of the `DataGridView` to `Public`. Then if the name of the instance of user control is `cCCustomers1`, then you can say `cCCustomers1.dgvCustomers.DataSource = db.Customers.ToList();`

Comment: Check your usercontrol tagprefix and TagName. depend on that you check your control id, and change code accordingly

Comment: @Angappan.S It's a Windows Forms question ;)

Comment: oh ok. check form1.designer.cs file. check control name.

Answer (score 1):

Your datagridview is **private** to the user control. You can confirm this by inspecting the `CCCustomers.designer.cs` file where the code for your datagridview is auto-generated.

The correct way to populate the datasource is to create a public method on your usercontrol eg

```
public void LoadData(List<Customer> customers)
{
    dgvCustomers.DataSource = customers;
}
```

which you would call from your main form like so:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    db = new DatabaseContext();
    CCCustomers.LoadData(db.Customers.ToList());
}
```